# Can't understand why text and urls are centred?

Tags: css

In my footer of http://bit.ly/gMmcMZ the text and urls are centered but I cannot find anything in the CSS that is making them center. Can anyone advise me please so I can change it and make them aligned left?

Comment: Everything is left-aligned for me, using FF8.

Comment: use firebug to debug the problem.

Comment: thanks everyone, I now see that I aligned the body center. Was trying to use margin auto but for some reason I've went and done that. You're all awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `text-align: center` in your CSS for the `body` element (which all inner elements will inherit from unless you override them).

Try being more specific for your styling i.e. `#footer li { text-align: left }`.

P.S. You should make use of Developer Tools (usually F12) on the browser, makes it a lot easier to determine these sort of things.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your `body` has `text-align: center;`

You need to override that with `text-align: left;`

Answer (score 0):

The surrounding `<p class="wordpress">` inherits the `text-align:center` of the `body`.

Just do `p.wordpress {text-align:right}` for example, or use a better qualifying class name for your footer if you need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

On line 5 of style.css you have

```
body {
    text-align: center;
}
```

This is centering all text on the page, take it out and the links in the footer are left aligned

Comment: If that style is in the body, I would assume that removing it would break a lot of styling in other areas. The fix here is to simply override the alignment on the footer, unless the OP doesn't need the body to be center aligned.

Comment: Agreed, would need to regression test. I'm just not a fan of putting that in the body

Answer (score 0):

The Reason is that you set the text-align property to center in body declaration of your css.

Answer (score 0):

your body contain `text-align:center` all childs within the body will follow the same css rule you need to write the independent css rule for that element.

```
#footer .wordpress {
margin-left: 140px;
font-size: 0.9em;
text-align: left;
}
```